# Time to execute a backup script to determine efficiency

Tags: scripts, ubuntu-mate

Creating the tar file seems slow to me. ( I learned 2 days ago that files in zip files do not retain file permissions.)

The tar file is 15 Mb in size.

It spends around 2 seconds to create the tar file.

It is copying from a 2 Tb drive to an old Maxtor drive. (300 Mb)

Should I include some timing code with a starting time and ending time and subtract the difference?

Or I could use time.

It would tell me how long it took to execute but then how would I know if the time was appropriate?

```
 # This is slow, need to investigate.
    cd $DOCS
    touch  /home/andy/Documents/$( date '+%m-%d-%Y' )
    tar -cvf Ubuntu_Documents.tar *.txt *.doc *.rtf *.html *.png *.pdf *.odt *.ods *.odg *.csv *.xls *.jpg 
    ## ONLY copy file if it's newer than destination file
    ##
    /usr/bin/rsync --progress -r -u Ubuntu_Documents.tar $Backup_Directory
    # for some reason, this is not working?
    /usr/bin/rsync --progress -r -u Ubuntu_Documents.tar $Local_Backup_Dir
```

Answer (score 1):

The utility `time` allows you to "time" a command, e.g.

```
time ls -R ~
```

will list total time it took to complete the command.